# there are some images in my windowsphone8 app which i want to be displayed when someone clicks on thumbnail of that image

Tags: button, windows-phone-8, click

Ihave Used Buttons To show thumbnails of image

```
<phone:PanoramaItem Header="gallery" Orientation="Horizontal" Foreground="#FFD8D36D" Height="611">
  <!--Double wide Panorama with large image placeholders-->
  <ScrollViewer Margin="0,4,16,37" >
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="878" Width="404" RenderTransformOrigin="0.491,0.995">

         <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Button Height="120" Width="120" Margin="12,0,0,0" Click="Button_Click_3">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="/gallery/1.png"/>
                </Button.Background>
              </Button>
              <Button Height="120" Width="120" Margin="12,0,0,0">
                <Button.Background>
                   <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="/gallery/2.png"/>
                 </Button.Background>
              </Button>
        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: the question is still too broad. How you want the image be displayed, in a new page? If that is the case in which part you have trouble : 1. *how to navigate to the new page?* 2. *how to pass some data (such as path to the clicked image) to the new page?* 3. *how to display image in WP?*

Comment: I want to display image (as in default windowsphone photo viewer do) when button is clicked.
Navigation of page is needed by me in the app